# Improving the time complexity of DFS using recursion such that each node only works with its descendants

Tags: algorithm, python-3.x, tree, language-agnostic, depth-first-search

#### Problem

There is a perfectly balanced m-ary tree that is n levels deep. Each inner node has exactly m child nodes. The root is said to be at depth 0 and the leaf nodes are said to be at level n, so there are exactly n ancestors of every leaf node. Therefore, the total number of nodes in the tree is:

```
T = 1 + m^2 + ... + m^n
  = (m^(n+1) - 1) / (m - 1)
```

Here is an example with m = 3 and n = 2.

```
            a              (depth 0)
   _________|________
   |        |        |
   b        c        d     (depth 1)
___|___  ___|___  ___|___
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
e  f  g  h  i  j  k  l  m  (depth 2)
```

I am writing a depth first search function to traverse the entire tree in deepest node first and leftmost node first manner, and insert the value of each node to an output list.

I wrote this function in two different ways and want to compare the time complexity of both functions.

Although this question is language agnostic, I am using Python code below to show my functions because Python code looks almost like pseudocode.

#### Solutions

The first function is `dfs1`. It accepts the root node as `node` argument and an empty output list as `output` argument. The function descends into the tree recursively, visits every node and appends the value of the node to the output list.

```
def dfs1(node, output):
    """Visit each node (DFS) and place its value in output list."""
    output.append(node.value)
    for child_node in node.children:
        dfs1(child_node, output)
```

The second function is `dfs2`. It accepts the root node as `node` argument but does not accept any list argument. The function descends into the tree recursively. At every level of recursion, on visiting every node, it creates a list with the value of the current node and all its descendants and returns this list to the caller.

```
def dfs2(node):
    """Visit nodes (DFS) and return list of values of visited nodes."""
    output = [node.value]
    for child_node in node.children:
        for s in dfs2(child_node):
            output.append(s)
    return output
```

#### Analysis

There are two variables that define the problem size.

- m -- The number of child nodes each child node has.
- n -- The number of ancestors each leaf node has (height of the tree).

In `dfs1`, O(1) time is spent while visiting each node, so the total time spent in visiting all nodes is

```
O(1 + m + m^2 + ... + m^n).
```

I don't bother about simplifying this expression further.

In `dfs2`, the time spent while visiting each node is directly proportional to all leaf nodes reachable from that node. In other words, the time spent while visiting a node at depth d is O(m^(n - d)). Therefore, the total spent time in visiting all nodes is

```
1 * O(m^n) + m * O(m^(n - 1)) + m^2 * O(m^(n - 2)) + ... + m^n * O(1)
= (n + 1) * O(m^n)
```

#### Question

Is it possible to write `dfs2` in such a manner that its time complexity is

```
O(1 + m + m^2 + ... + m^n)
```

without changing the essence of the algorithm, i.e. each node only creates an output list for itself and all its descendants, and does not have to bother with a list that may have values of its ancestors?

#### Complete working code for reference

Here is a complete Python code that demonstrates the above functions.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value):
        """Initialize current node with a value."""
        self.value = value
        self.children = []

    def add(self, node):
        """Add a new node as a child to current node."""
        self.children.append(node)

def make_tree():
    """Create a perfectly balanced m-ary tree with depth n.

    (m = 3 and n = 2)

                1              (depth 0)
       _________|________
       |        |        |
       2        3        4     (depth 1)
    ___|___  ___|___  ___|___
    |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
    5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13  (depth 2)
    """
    # Create the nodes
    a = Node( 1);
    b = Node( 2); c = Node( 3); d = Node( 4)
    e = Node( 5); f = Node( 6); g = Node( 7);
    h = Node( 8); i = Node( 9); j = Node(10);
    k = Node(11); l = Node(12); m = Node(13)

    # Create the tree out of the nodes
    a.add(b); a.add(c); a.add(d)
    b.add(e); b.add(f); b.add(g)
    c.add(h); c.add(i); c.add(j)
    d.add(k); d.add(l); d.add(m)

    # Return the root node
    return a

def dfs1(node, output):
    """Visit each node (DFS) and place its value in output list."""
    output.append(node.value)
    for child_node in node.children:
        dfs1(child_node, output)

def dfs2(node):
    """Visit nodes (DFS) and return list of values of visited nodes."""
    output = [node.value]
    for child_node in node.children:
        for s in dfs2(child_node):
            output.append(s)
    return output

a = make_tree()

output = []
dfs1(a, output)
print(output)

output = dfs2(a)
print(output)
```

Both `dfs1` and `dfs2` functions produce the same output.

```
['a', 'b', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'c', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'd', 'k', 'l', 'm']
['a', 'b', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'c', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'd', 'k', 'l', 'm']
```

Comment: If list concatenation is done lazily, then yes. Otherwise, probably not.

Comment: @rici I believe I have written the exact same expression, i.e. (m**(n+1)-1)/(m-1), in my question with just a different notation, i.e. `^` instead of `**`.

Comment: ah, so you did. i was looking at the second occurrence.

Answer (score 0):

If in dfs1 output list is passed by reference, then complexity of ds1 is O(total nodes).

Whereas, in dfs2 output list is returned and appended to parent's output list, thus taking O(size of list) for each return. Hence increasing overall complexity. You can avoid this overhead if both your append and returning of output list takes constant time.

This can be done if your output list is "doubly ended linked list". Hence you can return reference of output list and instead of append you can concatenate two doubly ended linked list (which is O(1)).